# Where can I find details about chromium/x-bookmark-entries?

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, chromium, specifications

After copying at least two bookmarks from google chrome it saves them to the clipboard using the format ID 49790 under the format name chromium/x-bookmark-entries.

I tried looking around chromium source code but I'm having trouble understanding the format.

Is the specification available ?

It is referenced here : [bookmark_node_data.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/bookmarks/browser/bookmark_node_data.cc)

Thanks.